# Comparing SimpleDateFormat output with number

Tags: java, if-statement, time, simpledateformat

I am making a program that executes something every time the time reaches an hour.

Here is the code:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
class NMAP {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
  Date date = new Date();
  if (dateFormat.format(date).equals(17)) {
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
  }
 }
}
```

It should be outputting `17` (since it is 17:00), but it doesn't output anything.

Why not?

Comment: Try `equals("17")`, or you are comparing a `String` with an `Integer` .

Comment: 17 gets auto-boxed to an Integer object with value 17. For the rest, see the duplicated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are comparing `dateFormat.equals(17)` a string against an integer

that returns false no matter what because they are different types.

you have to do `dateFormat.equals("17")`

---

And because some when you will need the power of java8:

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(now.getHour() == 17);
```